# CUDA cudaDeviceSynchronize complete Error codes reference?

Tags: cuda

I'm getting "**CudaDeviceSynchronize returned error code 75 after running** *some* **kernel**"

(sounds like something simple missing in my code)

BUT I failed to find any reference/Q&A/Topic about that code and cuda-memcheck ony refers to other errors, not the one that generated error code 75.

I was wondering is there any CUDA built-in function to describe this code?

or any official/unofficial (online) reference that lists the error codes ?

Thank you ! :)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

1. Find the function in cuda doc. `CudaDeviceSynchronize` is described [here](http://docs.nvidia.com/cuda/cuda-runtime-api/group__CUDART__DEVICE.html#group__CUDART__DEVICE_1g10e20b05a95f638a4071a655503df25d) as:

`__host__ ​ __device__ ​cudaError_t cudaDeviceSynchronize ( void )`

2. So your error code 75 is of type `cudaError_t`.
3. Find `cudaError_t` enum definition in cuda headers. It is in `include/driver_types.h`. And got error 75

:

```
/**
* While executing a kernel, the device encountered an instruction
* which can only operate on memory locations in certain address spaces
* (global, shared, or local), but was supplied a memory address not
* belonging to an allowed address space.
* The context cannot be used, so it must be destroyed (and a new one should be created).
* All existing device memory allocations from this context are invalid
* and must be reconstructed if the program is to continue using CUDA.
*/
cudaErrorInvalidAddressSpace          =     75,
```

Comment: You just learnt a man how to fish :) Thanks ! I was assigning a locally declared non-pointer variable to an element of a global array.